# 'Vector Search' not working in Elastic Search version 8.9.0

Tags: elasticsearch, vector-search

I'm trying to use the 'Vector Search' feature of elastic search which is available from version 8.0. I'm using the latest version 8.9.0, but I'm getting the **error: unknown field [vector_search]**

The query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "vector_search": {
      "query": "small forward",
      "fields": ["position"],
      "k": 10
    }
  }
}
```

Why is the query parameter "vector_search" not being recognized?

Comment: There's no `vector_search` query, but one called [`knn`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html). What is the documentation you're basing on to write your query?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly related to Elastic Search but Astra Vector Search is Lucene based and queries are pretty straightforward. This is powered by scalability and performance of Apache Cassandra. See a quick intro doc https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/vector-search/cql.html

Here is a sample query

```
SELECT * FROM vsearch.products 
ORDER BY item_vector ANN OF [0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.55]
LIMIT 1;
```